# Animation glitches on website

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I made a small scale experiment where I was testing an animation that would happen when you repeatedly hit the yellow square, in the jsfiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/aritro33/v86tE/5/

However, I am trying to move the animation seen in that jsfiddle to the jsfiddle here when you hit the compose/post circle/button. The animation would be applied to the posts. This is the jsfiddle:

I am having problems however, and after the 3+ times hitting the compose and post button, the animation falls apart.

Any ideas how to put the same animation seen in the first jsfiddle in the second jsfiddle for the posts?

Thanks so much to anyone who can help!

HTML for second experiment:

```
<div id="compose"><span id="firstspan">Compose</span>
 <span id="fourthspan">Post</span>

</div>
<span id="noposts">- No Posts Yet -</span>

<div id="composeheader">
    <input type="text" id="secondspan" value="Write Header Here:" />
</div>
<div id="thecolor"></div>
<div class="bubble">
    <input type="text" id="thehex" value="#2AC0A3" />
</div>
<div id="body"><span id="thirdspan" contenteditable="true">Write context text here:</span>

</div>
<ul id="allposts"></ul>
```

CSS for second experiment:

```
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100);
 body {
     background-color: #2D3E50;
 }

 #compose {
     height: 215px;
     width: 215px;
     background-color: #EBF1F1;
     border-radius: 150px;
     position: relative;
     left: 100px;
     top: 40px;
     color: #2c3e50;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
     -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
     transition: all 0.15s linear;
 }
 #compose:hover {
     background-color: #219B86;
     color: #EBF1F1;
 }
 #firstspan {
     font-size: 39px;
     font-family:'Roboto';
     position: relative;
     left: 22px;
     top: 75px;
 }
 #composeheader {
     height: 80px;
     width: 500px;
     background-color:#2AC0A3;
     position: relative;
     bottom: 175px;
     left: 365px;
     color: white;
 }
 #secondspan {
     color: white;
     font-family:'Roboto';
     font-size: 40px;
     position: relative;
     background-color: #2AC0A3;
     border: 1px solid #2AC0A3;
     left: 15px;
     top: 10px;
 }
 #body {
     min-height: 80px;
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 500px;
     background-color: #C6EEE6;
     position: relative;
     left: 365px;
     bottom: 275px;
     padding: 20px;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 #thirdspan {
     color: black;
     font-family:'Roboto';
     outline: 0px solid transparent;

 }

.thirdspan2{
     color: black;
     font-family:'Roboto';
     outline: 0px solid transparent;
}

 #thecolor {
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
     background-color: #2AC0A3;
     border-radius: 100px;
     position: relative;
     left: 365px;
     bottom: 315px;
 }
 .bubble {
     position: relative;
     left: 440px;
     bottom: 365px;
     width: 145px;
     height: 50px;
     padding: 0px;
     background: #FFFFFF;
     -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
 }
 .bubble:after {
     content:'';
     position: absolute;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 10px 15px 10px 0;
     border-color: transparent #FFFFFF;
     display: block;
     width: 0;
     z-index: 1;
     left: -15px;
     top: 15px;
 }
 #thehex {
     font-family:'Roboto';
     font-size: 20px;
     height: 30px;
     width: 115px;
     background-color: white;
     position: relative;
     border: 0px none;
     outline: 0px solid transparent;
     top: 10px;
     left: 28px;
 }
 .animated {
     -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
     -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
     -o-animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
     -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
     -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
     -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
     animation-fill-mode: both;
 }
 .animated.hinge {
     -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
     -ms-animation-duration: 2s;
     -o-animation-duration: 2s;
     animation-duration: 2s;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -moz-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-ms-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -ms-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-o-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -o-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -o-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -o-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -o-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 .bounceInDown {
     -webkit-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     -moz-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     -ms-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     -o-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     animation-name: bounceInDown;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -moz-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-ms-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -ms-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-o-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -o-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -o-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -o-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -o-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 .bounceInUp {
     -webkit-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -moz-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -ms-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -o-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     animation-name: bounceInUp;
 }
 #noposts {
     color: white;
     font-size: 39px;
     font-family:'Roboto';
     position: relative;
     left: 440px;
     bottom: 100px;
 }
 #fourthspan {
     color: #2c3e50;
     font-family:'Roboto';
     font-size: 39px;
     position: relative;
     left: 70px;
     top: 75px;
 }

ul#allposts li{
    min-height: 140px;
    width: 500px;


    position: relative;
    left: 239px;
    bottom: 432px;
}

.thecolor2{

    height: 50px;
width: 50px;
    border-radius: 100px;
background-color: #2AC0A3;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 591px;
    left: 325px;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.composeheader2{
  height: 80px;
     width: 500px;
     background-color:#2AC0A3;
     position: relative;
     bottom: 581px;
     left: 325px;
     color: white;

}

.secondspan2{
      color: white;
     font-family:'Roboto';
     font-size: 40px;
     background-color: #2AC0A3;
     border: 1px solid #2AC0A3;
    position: relative;
         left: 17px;
     top: 13px;

}

.body2{
         min-height: 80px;
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 500px;
     background-color: #C6EEE6;
     position: relative;
     left: 325px;
     bottom: 371px;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

JS for second experiment:

```
var clicktwice = false;

var color;
var forrgb;
var finalrgb2;
var myheader;

//198 238 230

//rgb(42, 192, 163) #2AC0A3

//rgb(198, 238, 230) #C6EEE6

//+156, +46, +67

$('#fourthspan').hide();
$('#thecolor').hide();
$('.bubble').hide();
$('#composeheader').hide();
$('#body').hide();

$('#compose').click(function () {

    setInterval(function () {
        $('#noposts').fadeTo(10, 0);
    }, 3000);

});

$("#thehex").keyup(function () {
    color = $("#thehex").val();

    forrgb = $("#thehex").val();
    $("#thecolor").css("background-color", color);
    $("#secondspan").css("background-color", color);
    $("#secondspan").css("border-color", color);
    $("#composeheader").css("background-color", color);
    forrgb = $('#thehex').val().replace('#', '');
    var reg = forrgb.length === 3 ? forrgb[0] + forrgb[0] + forrgb[1] + forrgb[1] + forrgb[2] + forrgb[2] : forrgb;
    var conv = reg.match(/.{2}/g);

    var r = parseInt(conv[0], 16);
    r = r + 156;
    var g = parseInt(conv[1], 16);
    g = g + 46;
    var b = parseInt(conv[2], 16);
    b = b + 67;

    var rgb = r + ',' + g + ',' + b;
    rgb = rgb.replace(/NaN/g, ' ... ');

    var finalrgb = ('rgb(' + rgb + ')');
    finalrgb2 = finalrgb;
    $("#body").css("background-color", finalrgb);

});

$('#compose').click(function () {
    if (clicktwice === false) {
        color = "#2AC0A3";
        finalrgb2 = "rgb(198, 238, 230)";
        $("#secondspan").val("Write Header Here:");
        $('#thirdspan').text("Write context text here:");
                $('#thehex').val(color);
            $("#thecolor").css("background-color", color);
    $("#secondspan").css("background-color", color);
    $("#secondspan").css("border-color", color);
    $("#composeheader").css("background-color", color);
            $("#body").css("background-color", finalrgb2);
         $('#thecolor').fadeTo(0, 1);
        $('#body').fadeTo(0,1);
        $('.bubble').fadeTo(0,1);
        $('#composeheader').fadeTo(0, 1);
        $('#firstspan').hide();
        $('#fourthspan').show();
        $('#thecolor').show();
        $('.bubble').show();
        $('#composeheader').show();
        $('#body').show();

  $(".composeheader2").animate({
    bottom: '-=248px'

  }, 400);

          $(".body2").animate({
    bottom:'-=248px'

  }, 400);

          $(".thecolor2").animate({
    bottom:'-=245px'

  }, 400);

        $('#thecolor').addClass('box animated bounceInDown');
        $('.bubble').addClass('box animated bounceInDown');
        $('#composeheader').addClass('box animated bounceInDown');
        $('#body').addClass('box animated bounceInDown');
        clicktwice = true;
    } else if (clicktwice === true) {

        myheader = $("#secondspan").val();
        $('.bubble').fadeTo(300, 0);
        $('#firstspan').show();
        $('#fourthspan').hide();
        clicktwice = false;
        var thestream = document.getElementById('allposts');

        var oneofpost = document.createElement('li');
        var thecolor2 = document.createElement('div');
        thecolor2.className = "thecolor2";
        var composeheader2 = document.createElement('div');
        composeheader2.className = "composeheader2";
        var secondspan2 = document.createElement('span');
        secondspan2.className = "secondspan2";
        var body2 = document.createElement('div');
        body2.className = "body2";
        var thirdspan2 = document.createElement('span');
        thirdspan2.className = "thirdspan2";




        var bodytext = $('#thirdspan').html();
        thirdspan2.innerHTML = bodytext;
        body2.style.backgroundColor = finalrgb2;
        secondspan2.innerHTML = myheader;
        thecolor2.style.backgroundColor = color;
        composeheader2.style.backgroundColor = color;
        secondspan2.style.backgroundColor = color;
        secondspan2.style.borderColor = color;
        $('#thecolor').fadeTo(0, 0);
        $('#body').fadeTo(0, 0);
        $('#composeheader').fadeTo(0, 0);


        thestream.appendChild(body2);
        thestream.appendChild(thecolor2);

        thestream.appendChild(composeheader2);
        composeheader2.appendChild(secondspan2);
        body2.appendChild(thirdspan2);
            $('#thecolor').removeClass('box animated bounceInDown');
        $('.bubble').removeClass('box animated bounceInDown');
        $('#composeheader').removeClass('box animated bounceInDown');
        $('#body').removeClass('box animated bounceInDown');



    }

});
```

Comment: Seems to be working OK here... Firefox v25.0

Comment: jsFiddle to make it easier http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/K5v6p/ It appears when you add a third post it overlays the 1st post (which is at the bottom) and then posts get added to the bottom

Comment: I cleaned up the code a little, you can combine the individual actions for show/hide etc. In the 2nd part of your `if` statement you are using standard JavaScript to create elements. Just use jQuery again, not mix and match unless you have to. Still not your issue, but makes it easier. http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/K5v6p/2/

Comment: Yes! It seems you understood my question -- do you know how I'd fix it? @jammykam

Comment: You don't know how much I appreciate you @jammykam

Comment: If you're not getting the kinds of answers you were looking for and need to clarify the question, please click the "edit" link under the question rather than posting a new one. You should post a new question if you're asking something substantially different from what you had originally asked (even if it's about the same code).

Comment: @aritro33 Hey, I updated my answer, did it help or not?

Comment: Yes -- thanks so much! You were a real help. @jammykam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've cleaned this up A LOT, the code should be much easier to read and follow now:

**HTML**

```
<script id="empty-message" type="html/template">
    <div class="message new box animated bounceInDown">
        <div class="thecolor"></div>
        <div class="bubble">
            <input type="text" class="hexcolor" value="#2AC0A3" />
        </div>
        <div class="composeheader">
            <input type="text" value="Write Header Here:" />
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <span contenteditable="true">Write context text here:</span>
        </div>
    </div>    
</script>

<div id="message-actions">
    <span class="compose">Compose</span>
    <span class="post">Post</span>
</div>
<div id="no-posts">- No Posts Yet -</div>
<div id="all-posts"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var getRGB = function(color) {
        var rgb = color.replace('#', '');       
        rgb = rgb.length === 3 ? rgb[0] + rgb[0] + rgb[1] + rgb[1] + rgb[2] + rgb[2] : rgb;

        var conv = rgb.match(/.{2}/g);
        var r = parseInt(conv[0], 16) + 156;
        var g = parseInt(conv[1], 16); + 46;
        var b = parseInt(conv[2], 16); + 67;

        rgb = r + ',' + g + ',' + b;
        rgb = rgb.replace(/NaN/g, ' ... ');
        rgb = ('rgb(' + rgb + ')');
        return rgb;
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#all-posts').on('keyup', '.message.new .hexcolor', function () {
        var color = $(this).val();
        $(".message.new .thecolor, .message.new .composeheader").css("background-color", color);    
        $(".message.new .body").css("background-color", getRGB(color));
    });

    $('#message-actions').click(function () {

        if ($('.compose').is(':visible')) { 
            $('#all-posts').prepend($('#empty-message').html());
        } else {       
            var $message = $('#all-posts .message:first').removeClass('new box animated bounceInDown');
            $message.find('.composeheader > input').attr('readonly', true);
            $message.find('.body > span').attr('contenteditable', false);
        }

        $('#no-posts').hide();
        $('.compose, .post').toggle();

    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100);

/* css for animation */

.animated {
     -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
     -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
     -o-animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
     -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
     -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
     -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
     animation-fill-mode: both;
 }
 .animated.hinge {
     -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
     -ms-animation-duration: 2s;
     -o-animation-duration: 2s;
     animation-duration: 2s;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -moz-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-ms-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -ms-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-o-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -o-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -o-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -o-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -o-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 .bounceInDown {
     -webkit-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     -moz-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     -ms-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     -o-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     animation-name: bounceInDown;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -moz-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-ms-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -ms-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-o-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -o-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -o-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -o-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -o-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 .bounceInUp {
     -webkit-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -moz-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -ms-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -o-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     animation-name: bounceInUp;
 }


 /* page */

 body {
     background-color: #2D3E50;
     font-family:'Roboto';
     min-width: 960px;
 }


 /* message compose */

 .message { 
    margin-top: 40px;
}

 .composeheader {
     background-color:#2AC0A3;
     color: white;
     padding: 10px 15px;
     clear: both;
 }

 .composeheader INPUT {
     color: white;
     font-size: 40px;
     background-color: transparent;
     border-width: 0;
     font-family: 'Roboto';
 }

 .body {
     min-height: 80px;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 20px;
     background-color: #C6EEE6;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body > span {
     color: black;     
     outline: 0px solid transparent;
}

.thecolor {
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
     background-color: #2AC0A3;
     border-radius: 100px;
     float: left;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.bubble { display: none; }

 .message.new .bubble {
     height: 50px;
     padding: 0px;
     background: #FFFFFF;
     -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     float: left;
     margin-left: 20px;
     display: block;
 }

 .bubble:after {
     content:'';
     position: absolute;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 10px 15px 10px 0;
     border-color: transparent #FFFFFF;
     display: block;
     width: 0;
     z-index: 1;
     left: 55px;
     top: 15px;
 }

 .hexcolor {     
     font-size: 20px;
     height: 30px;
     width: 100px;
     background-color: transparent;
     border-width: 0px;
     margin: 10px 5px
 }

 /* compose button */

 #message-actions {
     height: 215px;
     width: 215px;
     background-color: #EBF1F1;
     border-radius: 150px;
     position: relative;
     color: #2c3e50;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
     -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
     transition: all 0.15s linear;
     float: left;
     margin: 40px 100px 10px;
 }

 #message-actions:hover {
     background-color: #219B86;
     color: #EBF1F1;
 }

 #no-posts {
     color: white;
     font-size: 39px;     
     float: left;
     margin-top: 120px;
 }

 .compose {
     font-size: 39px;     
     position: relative;
     left: 22px;
     top: 75px;
 }

 .post {
     color: #2c3e50;     
     font-size: 39px;
     position: relative;
     left: 70px;
     top: 75px;
     display: none;
}

/* messages */

#all-posts {
    min-height: 140px;
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/K5v6p/14/)

Use meaningful names for your `id`s and css classes, it makes the code much easier to follow and understand what is going on. Styles such as "firstspan" mean nothing and means you have to keep looking back at the markup to figure out context.

<strike>I've cleaned this up as best I can, I'm not good with CSS3 or the animation stuff, I'll leave it to you to fix that up.</strike> I think this should be working exactly as you expect now, messages slide down and are added to the stack top down.

EDIT 2:
I changed a lot of the ID selectors to use and refactored the code to make it much simpler. You were also setting the ID on the newly created elements which were all the same, this is wrong and will cause you issues further down the line (ID's should be unique per page).
I cleaned up the JS, combining multiple statements which did the same thing with different selectors. You were using a lot of standard JavaScript `getElementById` type calls, I changed these create the DOM elements using jQuery instead.

I used an `html/template` script declaration to create the new elements, it's much cleaner than using jQuery to built up your new DOM elements. Also, your compose and post elements were essentially the same thing. Don't repeat CSS styles, either combine multiple selectors, or just re-use the same structure as I have done. Hopefully the changes make sense.